# long distance network

Tags: networking

okay so, I just opened up two shops in my hometown.

The two stores is about 6 blocks apart, connecting them by wire is not really feasible in cost wise.
What kind of network topology should I use for my small shops, there will be 5 computers, one is the sales computer ,another 4 as mentioned is the guest computer. I want the sales and guest computers network to be seperated. Both shops have same computers.

The guest computers serves up simple website that has my shop catalog on it, I'm thinking of using a web server.

So, how am i suppose to setup these networks, im planning to add in more computers in the future.
Is it I need to station a single server at a shop, and all the computer connected to it? or is there any more effective methods?

I'm no networking expert, would love to hear some advice.

Comment: Your suggestion of a single server would probably be your best option. Obviously linking them to a single network would be costly, but having a central server (web & file share etc) would be fairly straightforward.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams hi, yea central server is good but what if in the future, I plan to have a lot more computers connected to it, would there be any problems?

Comment: If in the future you plan to add a lot more computers I should imagine you would be in a position to afford either getting a single network installed or renting server space to serve up all your needs. For your current setup (with a half decent computer) you can easily manage a simple web and file share system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about renting a small (V)-Server for about 10€ (Or less) a month which serves the website and is running a VPN-Server? You would have then 3 Networks, two physical, one virtual. Every shop gets a normal router, which is connected to the internet. Then all computers in the shops connect to the VPN, so you get one big virtual Network. You could configure the server to only serve the website on the VPN. I think that would be much much cheaper then connecting them physically via wire or wireless etc.
You can create more then one Subnet with help of the VPN Server, so you can seperate the networks as you like.

Comment: You could of curse host the server yourself if you don't want to rent one.

Comment: great advice.  so I would just need two routers, in each shops? each of them will be connecting to the vpn server I rented?

Comment: Thats right. I would suggest to not rent a VPN-Server, but a V-Server. You will have to configure everything yourself but you can do much more with a V-Server (Like serving the website). You cant even configure a VPN-Server sometimes. Setting it up yourself (And with the help of Superuser :P) Would be better. The rest is correct :)

Comment: oh i see, great advice, I will look it up and setup myself. thanks again.

Comment: Thats why I'm here :P Come back if you need help.

Answer (score -1):

Reset your expectations, you can't afford to connect two differing sites across "six blocks"
A block typically measured in a 1/10th of  a mile, you want to stretch WiFi or some equivalent hefty pipe across .6 miles or longer.

Plan to beg property owners for permission to install weather grade roof repeaters in a mesh network.

Apply for an expensive portfolio of licensed industrial grade microwave to span that distance in point to point, you clearly have no idea of what's involved nor prepared to spend fortunes more than the costs of installing broadband in your businesses.

Comment: hm i see, how about bringing my server online, so that they can be accessed from the other shop.

Comment: you're lost already, based on your question, you CAN'T afford to "wire", meaning you can't afford paying for services with an ISP even a phone line nor DSL, cable, blah, blah. There is a "total cost of ownership" factor, two disparate web servers at independently managed sites for supporting a business will cost more than buying an ISP to unify a network,  your two businesses are going to have far more pressing concerns if this is your starting point.